# VS2012 Error from Entity Data Model: "Could not parse configuration file."

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-4, output

I have .NET C# project that uses Entity Framework 4.0. When I load the project in Visual Studio, I get a message every time in my Output window:

`Could not parse configuration file. The error message is: 'An item with same key has already been added.'. Try editing the file manually then saving it.`

The "Show output from:" dropdown is set to Entity Data Model.

This doesn't seem to be affecting functionality anywhere, but I've been receiving this message for months and have not been able to track it down. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a very similar error message, turns out a bad source control merge added some extra characters to my web.config.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was two lines (used to store the connection string) with the same key in the App.config of the project. Probably a result of a careless merge too.

Comment: If you are keeping two connection string settings in your web.config with one set commented out, the (EF4, legacy code) EDMX parser ignores the XML comments when parsing web.config.

Comment: In my case the lines were not commented out.